# Environment of 'onecolumn' does not reset back to 'twocolumn'

Tags: environments

When I creating a two-column document and use an environment using `onecolumn`, it does not reset back to the `twocolumn` counterpart after the `\end{onecolumn}`.

An example would be

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside,twocolumn,openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Two columns}
  \lipsum[1-5]

  \begin{onecolumn}
    \chapter{One column}
    \lipsum[1-4]
  \end{onecolumn}

  \chapter{Two columns again, but it's not}
  \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

I've read on here I can just repeat the `\twocolumn` switch, but this seems counter-intuitive since I specifically used `begin` and `end`. I haven't found much information about these environments and I'm unsure if I'm doing something wrong or have the wrong expectations.

Comment: `\onecolumn` is not designed to be an environment you need `\twocolumn` to force a page break and re-set the two column settings simply ending the group is not enough

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of this. Could you post it as an answer then I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\onecolumn` is not designed to be an environment: you need `\twocolumn` to force a page break and re-set the two column settings. Simply ending the group by ending an environment is not enough.